# Google App Engine run code takes longer than 60 sec

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Ok I guess it's time to give up, I've been trying almost everything with the deferred function to try running my code that takes longer than those 60 sec. I tried TaskQueues which I couldn't make work, then I tried deferred function which seems to be the right way to do it. I can get a function running fine, but when I want to know when it is done, by calling the MainHandler's self.response.out.write and write something out on screen. I get PickleError. I tried creating a new python file and import it, so I dont do it in the MainHandler, I tried creating a new class before using the deferred. Nothing works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: create a handler that checks memcache for a particular value. If it's not there, display "not complete". Then when your deferred task completes get it to write that value to memcache. Then refresh your first handler - when it says "complete" your task is complete. You don't use deferred tasks for things that need to write data out to the user, that's the entire point of them (as they will complete execution after the deadline has expired in any case) so you need to find ways to communicate via memcache or urlfetch or similar.

Comment: It seems like it's not the right way to do this. Maybe I should find another approach.

Comment: use backends :) And get used to the idea that some things will run but you can only access their results indirectly - tasks cannot write to the response, they run separate from it and can write to memcache, DB but not the response.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check out AppEngine [Backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/):

> Backends are special App Engine instances that have no request
>   deadlines, higher memory and CPU limits, and persistent state across
>   requests.

Hoep it helps.